# Possible to use both OpenCV 2.x and OpenCV3 in the same project?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I have a project based on OpenCV 2.4.11. I would like to use some of the functionality available in OpenCV3 without porting my whole application over.

My question is, is it possible to use both OpenCV 2.x and 3.x in the same project?

For reference I am building on OSX, within XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to load the OpenCV 2.X library or the OpenCV 3 library. An app cannot simultaneously call both.